# react: use text for mobile only if text mobile is not null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi I receive a JSON file with an array of objets and I need to add mobile text only if it exists, else display the text to the desktop.
I did: `{ismobile?(props.data.titleMobile?(<h1>{props.data.titleMobile}</h1>):(<h1>{props.data.title}</h1>)):(<h1>{props.data.title}</h1>)}`
It works!!!.

But it doesn't make sense to do it for 100 variables,

Everything else I tried resulted in duplicate code,

I was thinking of changing the JSON to: "title"(all text not only title):{desktop:123, mobile:456}
and build a function that checks:

```
 func text(x){
if(isMobile&&x.mobile)
return x.mobile;
else
return x.desktop;
}
```

but it is a lot of work to change the Json.

I would appreciate help if anyone has an idea

Thanks

Comment: You should post json

Comment: You can write a function: `function t(key) { return props.data[isMobile ? key + "Mobile" : key]; }` then use `<h1>{t("title")}</h1>`

Comment: But yeah, restructuring the texts object you receive is also a way to solve this.